# Signatures of symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, transpose

I've never seen the term signature of a matrix before this exercise I'm given, and understand it simply means the number of positive eigenvalues.

Anyway:

Let $A_1, A_2$ be real invertible symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices. I need to determine the possible values for their signatures, and also prove that if they're not congruent, they're simultaneously congruent to diagonal matrices.

Pretty helpless here..

Comment: No, the signature is **not** the number of positive eigenvalues.  It is the numbers of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues (for a real symmetric matrix): different authors might put these in different orders.  However, if the matrix is invertible it's determined by the number of positive eigenvalues.

Comment: See [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_law_of_inertia)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: one of $A$ and $B$, let's say $A$, is similar to (and WLOG may be considered equal to) either $I$ or $-I$. You can explicitly solve the equations 
$$(S^T S)_{1,2} = 0,\ (S^T B S)_{1,2} = 0 $$